# how to improve strcmp mysql performance comparing similar strings

Tags: mysql, performance, text, comparison, strcmp

I hope this is not a duped question. I've looking around and can't find any question like mine, but...

I have a table containing people's data, and we know there are duplicates. The table contains more than 30k entries and is live growing. The expected max volume is around 100k.
I'm running a process to find out the duplicated entries, BUT, and here is the BUT... the duplicates are "similar" entries, not exact duplicated entries.

The criteria is as follows: we consider it duplicate if they belong to the same group and have a similar name.

Same group is just a join with another table, properly indexed, etc. That part works fine.

Similar name means equal name ignoring case, trimmed and ignoring internal spaces. So " joHn sMith" (initial blank space) is equal to "JOHN      SMITH  " (intermediate and final spaces) and equal to " john  smith  " (initial, intermediate and final spaces).

My initial strategy is super slow: I have a view and one stored parsing the view. The stored removes the duped entries one by one, as the duped removal is complex and affects several other tables.

The stored works more or less efficient, but the view is horrible.

The view joins the table with the people to itself and the plan shows that, of course, the problem is in the full scan on the people's table for each comparison:

strcmp(replace(lcase(trim(`s`.`name`)),' ',''),replace(lcase(trim(`t`.`name`)),' ','')) = 0

Note that s. and t. refer to the same people's table.

Any suggestions?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of MySQL is used?

Comment: Similarity is a tough problem.  MySQL has no "good" solutions.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov, 8.2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question whether a person is a direct child of a single group, or a member of multiple groups. Assuming the former, I would just:

```sql
WITH dupes AS (
    SELECT id, MIN(id) OVER w AS replace_with_id
    FROM people
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY group_id, LCASE(REPLACE(name, ' ', '')))
)
SELECT *
FROM dupes
WHERE id <> replace_with_id;
```

With your projected max row count of only 100k rows, this should be much faster than your non-sargable self-join. Testing with 0.01% dupe rate on a random (ish) set of 300k rows, it returned 34 rows for merging/replacement in ~70ms.

Comment: Hi, for the purpose of this problem, a person is a direct child of a group. In a later stage things get more complex, but that's once the dupes are cleaned.

Comment: In that case, this should work fine. If not, please update your question with some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Hi again, it looks like my SQL is a little rusty... but is nice to see more advanced syntax. I'm translating your code to my example, but I miss a join somewhere. The tables design contains the groups in a n/m intermediate table. So the people's table does not contain any info on the group, is the people-group where this is stored, so I guess that you need to join with that one, right? how should it be rewritten? From people p, join people-group pg,,, partition by pg.group_id ?

Comment: Here's an example with the join - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-1qAGJCv). This only works if the user is a member of only one group.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

1. Add a new column to hold the canonical name; e.g. the name converted to all-caps with extraneous spaces and other characters removed.
2. Populate the column.
3. Add an index for the column.
4. Deduplicate by reading records in order on the canonical name and merging / otherwise dealing with duplicate records.

(It is debatable whether you should keep the original column with the  non-canonical form of the names.)

In rough terms, the complexity is as follows:

1. Is O(1).
2. Is O(N).
3. Is O(NlogN).
4. Is O(N).  That is O(1) for each record!

I think ...

Comment: I would add that the new column should be a generated column, which will take care of automatically transforming names to their format required for the comparison.

Comment: Hmmm ... can you put an index on a generated column?

Comment: Yes, you can index generated columns.

Comment: If you have cleaned the table you can also set a unique index on the group and on the generated column and delete the simple index.
This allows you to directly prevent the creation of new duplicates

Comment: Hi @StephenC, I can't alter the original table, so I presume this means creating a temporal table for running the operations? This is why I was working with the view, rather than a table, but of course the views can't have the indexes we can use in a table. I'm coming from Oracle, and if I'm not mistaken, we can't have a materialized view in MySQL, right? Any alternative to create a temporal table?